# Make BusyIndicator run when click on button (signal to C++)

Tags: qt, qml

I created an interface has a ListView and two Buttons. When click on **Scan** button it will call to C++ and make change to the model of ListView. After that C++ will emit signal to inform model is changed therefore ListView in QML will update with new model. I want to make BusyIndicator running during that process. How can i do that ?.

I saw a few solutions on stackoverflow like this one: [BusyIndicator does not show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222247/busyindicator-does-not-show-up) but none of them worked for my case.

Can anyone help me ? Thanks.

Here is my qml code:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import Qt.labs.controls 1.0

Rectangle
{
    objectName: "bluetoothPage"
    anchors.fill: parent

    property var bluetoothDataModel: messageFromApp.bluetoothData
    onBluetoothDataModelChanged: listView.update()

    signal qmlScanButtonSignal()
    signal qmlDisconnectButtonSignal()

    ColumnLayout
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 6

        RowLayout
        {
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            Text
            {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: "Connect with ECU"
                font.bold: true
                font.pixelSize: 20
            }

            BusyIndicator
            {
                id: busyIndicator
                Layout.preferredWidth: 30
                Layout.preferredHeight: 30
                running: false
                visible: false
            }
        }

        GroupBox
        {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            title: qsTr("Available device:")

            ListView
            {
                id: listView
                anchors.fill: parent
                model: bluetoothDataModel
                delegate: Component
                          {
                              Item
                              {
                                    width: parent.width
                                    height: 40
                                    Column
                                    {
                                        Text { text: "Name:" + model.modelData.name }
                                        Text { text: "Number:" + model.modelData.macAddress }
                                    }
                                    MouseArea
                                    {
                                        anchors.fill: parent
                                        onClicked: listView.currentIndex = index
                                    }
                               }
                           }
                highlight: Rectangle
                           {
                                color: "blue"
                           }
            }
        }

        RowLayout
        {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: 10

            Button
            {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: "Scan"
                onClicked: qmlScanButtonSignal()
            }

            Button
            {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: "Disconnect"
                onClicked: qmlDisconnectButtonSignal()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only this solution worked for me in my case. However, like everybody said using `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`
 is really bad practice. I also try to using QThread but it got crash when emitted signal inside thread. If you guy have any futher solutions, please let me now. I'm really appreciate. Thanks.

**QML**

```
BusyIndicator {
    running: CPPModule.busy
}
```

**CPP**

```
void CPPModule::setBusy(const bool &busy)
{
    m_busy = busy;
    emit busyChanged();
}
void CPPModule::InsertIntoDB()
{
    setBusy(true);
    QThread::msleep(50);
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    /*
    very Long Operation
    */
    setBusy(false);
}
```

Another solution is this:

```
Timer {
   id: myTimer
   interval: 1
   onTriggered: {
        app.someLongRunningFunction();
        myActivityIndicator.visible = false;
   }
}

Butoon{
    ....
    onClicked: {
        myActivityIndicator.visible=true;
        myTimer.start();
    }
}
```