# Avoid QQuickView delayed qml loading

Tags: qt, qml

Here's my situation. I'm trying to combine qml with a mostly widget based UI. To do this, I'm using QQuickView with QWidget::createWindowContainer. I can't use QQuickWidget, because I need to convert the window into a native window, and QQuickWidget doesn't like that. But back to the issue.

My problem is that the first time the view is displayed, it takes like half a second to load causing a very obvious flicker. After that I can hide/show the view all I want, it displays immediately. It's only the first time the qml loads. And I'm fairly certain it's the loading of the qml that causes the issue. Because I have two different QQuickViews that get the same qml as their source. But after any one of them loads once, the other has no issues displaying instantly.

I tried to call show() on view early to get it to load in time. But this causes the qml to appear for a brief moment before any of the widgets get displayed.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? How can I get the QQuickView to behave.

Edit: I'm using Qt 5.4.2, and I can't update to a newer version due to various reasons.

Answer (score 3):

I was going to say that you can use the same approach as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27251405/904422) answer, but it seems that even that is too early to being loading the QML. It's hacky, but the only other thing I can think of is using a very short `Timer`:

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtQuick>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) :
        QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
        QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, this);
        container->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
        view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("window", view);
        view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
        setCentralWidget(container);
        resize(400, 400);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent

//    Connections {
//        target: window
//        onAfterSynchronizing: loader.active = true
//    }

    Timer {
        running: true
        repeat: true
        interval: 50
        onTriggered: {
            loader.active = true
        }
    }

    Loader {
        id: loader
        active: false
        sourceComponent: Column {
            anchors.fill: parent

            Repeater {
                model: 30000
                delegate: Button {
                    text: index
                }
            }
        }
    }

    BusyIndicator {
        running: loader.status === Loader.Null
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

For brevity, I chucked the "heavy" QML into `sourceComponent`, but you can also use the `source` property to point to a URL.

`BusyIndicator` runs its animation on the render thread, so it can continue to spin while the GUI thread is blocked.

Comment: I looked into your solution, but then noticed you used qml components that I don't have access to. I apologise, I should have mentioned it in the question. But hopefully this will be useful information to others with similar issues.

Comment: You can change `import QtQuick.Controls 2.0` to `import QtQuick.Controls 1.3` (or whatever version of Controls was released with Qt 5.4.2) and it should work just the same.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I must have looked up something wrong.
I managed to try out your solution, but sadly it won't solve my issue.
This is useful, if you have a complicated qml that takes time to load. My problem is that even a very simple one button qml takes a split second to load for the first time.

With your solution, the loader itself takes a split second to appear, and I can just barely make out the loading circle before my qml appears.